# Helper codeigniter not calling in function ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-helpers

i've used codeigniter relative_time helper [created by yoeran](https://github.com/yoeran/CodeIgniter-RelativeTimeHelper). in ajax post i call function in controller to return relative time and admin name. but relative time alwayas return null. is helper not calling in ajax post ?

here my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST"
        , url: baseurl +"admin/get_last_change/document"
        , dataType: "json"
        , data: {
            id: $(".page-heading small").attr('data-document-id')
        }
        , success: function (result) {
            $('#last-change').html(result.data);
            console.log(result.data);
        }
    });
```

and here my function in controller :

```
function get_last_change($keyword){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $where = array('target_id' => $id);
        if($keyword == 'document'){
            $result = $this->Admin_Model->get_task_admin(12, $where);
            $admin_name = $result->row('admin_account_name');
            $last_change = relative_time($result->row('created_at'));
            $data = "Last Change : ".$last_change." by <span class='text-primary'>".$admin_name."</span>";   
            $output = array('data' => $data);
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

result of $result :

```
{"id":"12","created_at":"2016-05-17 09:52:14","admin_account_name":"Ibnu Habibie","task_name":"Add Content"}
```

Comment: did you load the `$this->load->model("Admin_Model")`?

Comment: yes i do . @user2352577L

Comment: Did you `$this->load->helper('relative_time');' ?

Comment: yes i do @YinGang . i call it in __construct() . other function used relative_time is working properly but it's not calling in ajax.

Comment: if you sure both that have loaded, please check your config file `global_xss_filtering`, if the value is ture, it will filter the string that some invalid characters that you contain. Make sure it is false.

Comment: @user2352577L it's already false.

Comment: what is the return of `$result `?

Comment: @user2352577L i've added a result of $result.

Comment: if you use `print_r` is that format which you gave me, the code should be `$result->created_at;` not  `$result->row('created_at');`

Comment: yeah i know . @user2352577L . i just used it for show a return of $result.

Comment: so you means that you can get the `created_at`, right?

Comment: yes, if i don't use relative_time helper it return created_at @user2352577L.

Comment: i have tried the helper with `function relative_time($time="2016-05-17 09:52:14")` which is work for me, you need to test your time is string or not. use `var_dump` to watch it.

Comment: i've used var_dump and created_at return a string. @user2352577L